# i want to run two Command in BatchScript ToGether

Tags: batch-file

i want to run two Command in BatchScript ToGether

i want, drivetype=3 and drivetype=2 run ToGether

> & not working below Command!:(

```
if %2==9  for /f "tokens=2 delims==:" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get caption /format:list & wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" get caption /format:list') do >"%TEMP%\%%a.txt" tree %%a:\ /a /f
```

Comment: You need to escape the ampersand. `^&`.

Comment: You can actually simplify your `WMIC` command. `wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3 or drivetype=2" get caption /format:list`

Answer (score 1):

You can use WQL keyword `OR` to include both your drivetypes in a single result.

Here's a single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example:

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=:" %%A In ('^""%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe" LogicalDisk Where "DriveType='2' Or DriveType='3'" Get Caption 2^>NUL^|"%__APPDIR__%find.exe" ":"^"')Do @"%__APPDIR__%tree.com" %%A:\ /F /A>"%TEMP%\%%A.txt"
```

*BTW, I would suggest either `If %~2 Equ 9` or the safer `If "%~2" == "9"`.*

Answer (score 0):

The general way of starting different commands simultaneously in batch, is using the [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command:

```
start cmd1
start cmd2
```

Be careful about the `/wait` switch: this one makes sure you only start the second command when the first is finished.